# res.sendStatus gives an error in Express application

Tags: express

I get an error with the `sendStatus()` function below when I hover on it. The error is:

> Property 'sendStatus' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)

My code:

```
import express from 'express';
import {Request, Response} from "express";

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/blogapi/posts', (req:Request,res : Response) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Please help

Comment: This looks like you're not using the proper typing for Express and just have the typing from a plain HTTP response object.  `.sendStatus()` is an Express-specific method.

Comment: Thank you!! I did an 'npm install @types/express' and this resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you're not using the proper typing for Express and just have the typing from a plain HTTP response object. `.sendStatus()` is an Express-specific method.

As you've discovered, `npm install @types/express` will install the appropriate types for Express.

Answer (score 0):

You should use res.status, sendStatus does not exist in response.

```
import express from "express";
import { Request, Response } from "express";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/blogapi/posts", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).send();
});
```

Comment: I am using Typescript. The above code also given an error. Do I need to upgrade express to a higher version

Comment: `.sendStatus()` exists in [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus) which is what the OP is using.